# Using a subset of tfrecord

Tags: tensorflow, tfrecord

Is it possible to use an existing `tfrecord` for one or a subset of the labels which was used to generate it

I'm training several models with the same data each would require only a one or a subset of labels used to originally create the `tfrecord`. The `tfrecord` is quite large so I want to about create one for each models subset of labels.

Answer (score 0):

`tf.data.Dataset`s have `filter`, `skip` and `take` methods which you may find useful. Alternatively you could split your original dataset across multiple tfrecord files and create a `Dataset` based on a subset of those files.

If you are happy to recreate the data using `tensorflow_datasets`, [splits](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/splits) may also give you what you want.